# What's the difference between "if (isupper(argument) == true)" and " if (isupper(argument))"? Note: argument is any char in my program

Tags: c, cs50

I was doing CS50's Caesar problem set and when I tried to shift uppercased letters, using `if (isupper(argument) == true)` to check wether the character I wanted to shift was uppercased, it didin't work, it thought that uppercased letters weren't, in fact, uppercase. When I switched it up to `if (isupper(argument))`, the program correctly shifted uppercased letters.
Is there any difference between those two formats?
Here's the code I used (i'm referring to the code within the for loop):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Check wether there is only 1 command line argument
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        //Check if there is any character that's not a digit
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) == false)
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    //Convert key to an int
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);
    
    //Prompt plaintext
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    string ciphertext = plaintext;
    
    //Shift ciphertext's characters by the amount of "key"
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        //If it isn't a letter, do nothing
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]) == false)
        {
            ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
        }
        else
        {
            //If it's uppercase
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]) == true)
            {
                //Convert ASCII to alphabetical index
                plaintext[i] -= 'A';
                //Shift alphabetical index
                ciphertext[i] = (plaintext[i] + key) % 26;
                //Convert alphabetical index to ASCII
                ciphertext[i] += 'A';
            }
            //If it's lowercase
            else if (islower(plaintext[i]))
            {
                //Convert ASCII to alphabetical index
                plaintext[i] -= 'a';
                //Shift alphabetical index
                ciphertext[i] = (plaintext[i] + key) % 26;
                //Convert alphabetical index to ASCII
                ciphertext[i] += 'a';
            }
        
        }

    }
    
    //Print ciphertext
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
}
```

Comment: Save the result into a variable first, before making your assumption, because the function should return the result first, then the resulting comparisons are done. For example, int result = isupper(argument); then review the contents of "result" by debugging/breakpoint. I'm not saying that's the correct way do code it, but for this situation gives you additional insight that I think will be valuable.

Comment: `true` is *one* of the values that has thruthiness.

Comment: @rici so it is, good catch.

Comment: @rici They _are_ in `stdbool.h` but if it were valid/recommended to use them with `isupper` et. al., wouldn't/shouldn't `ctype.h` itself have to include `stdbool.h` and the macros would have to ensure a true 1/0 boolean value?

Comment: @craig: if `isupper` returned `bool` or even `_Bool`, it would be acceptable to compare with `true`. Even then I wouldn't do it and I don't think you would either. `if (booleanValue == true)` is noise. But it's inappropriate to say (as the now-redacted comment did) that you shouldn't use `true` and `false` *because they are not standard*. They are standard, and they have uses. This is not one of them, and it needs to be explained why that's the case. (And it has been.)

Comment: @craig: i deleted the comment because what it was a response to no longer exists

Comment: Incidentally, you should ensure any value you pass to the `<ctype.h>` functions is non-negative or is `EOF`. If `char` is signed, it can have negative values. The C standard does not define the behavior in this case. If `x` is a `char` and could be negative, you should pass `(unsigned char) x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

int isupper(int) does not return a boolean (a 0 or 1 value). It returns a non-zero int if the arg is uppercase.

the difference between the two conditions is that one compares the return value to one and the other compares the return value to non-zero.

Answer (score 6):

When you have something that you think of as true/false, never write

```
if(thing == true)
```

or

```
if(thing == false)
```

Just write

```
if(thing)
```

or

```
if(!thing)
```

It turns out that `isupper()` and `islower()` and the rest of the isxxx functions in `<ctype.h>` return zero/nonzero for false/true, but *not* necessarily 0/1.  If `isupper('A')` returns, say, 4, then `if(isupper(argument))` will work as you expect, but `if(isupper(argument) == true)` will always fail.

See also [question 9.2](http://c-faq.com/bool/bool2.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Good practice. However, while the `true` test is bad,  the `false` test is okay [bad style perhaps] (e.g. `(thing == 0) === (! thing)`). Personally, I never use the `true/false` defines, but the second one will [always] work.

Comment: Good reference.

Comment: Oh wow, it's so clear to me now! That was really well put, thank you :)

Comment: Some annoying detail: If you run cppcheck it will throw warnings: "[misra-c2012-14.4] The controlling expression of an if statement and the controlling expression of an iteration statement shall have essentially Boolean type" even for code like `if (function_returning_bool())`. How much more "essentially Boolan" than return type `bool` could it get?

Answer (score 0):

It is bad style to compare a truth value (boolean expression) with a truth constant

```
if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) == false) // Bad style
if (!isdigit(argv[1][i]))         // Better

if (isupper(argument) == true) // Bad style
if (isupper(argument))         // Better
```

In the case of `isupper` there is a hidden **bug**. In order to be "true" it suffices in C to be non-zero. But `true` is defined as 1 in C.

The `==/!= true/false` also shows second-rating booleans, you could as well have done `(X == true) == true`. Redundant and hiding the original condition as first rank citizen. It shows a missing bit of programming knowledge *(not serious though)*.

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (7.4.1 Character classification functions)

> 1 The functions in this subclause return **nonzero** (true) if and
> only if the value of the argument c conforms to that in the
> description of the function.

That is in C any non-zero value used in a condition is considered as a logical true. It is not the same as the constant `true` defined in header `<stdbool.h>`. That is any of the functions `isdigit`, `isalpha` or `isupper` can return any non-zero value as a true value. But it does not mean that the function will return exactly the constant `1` defined in the header `<stdbool.h>` as the macro `true`. So instead for example this if statement

```
if (isupper(plaintext[i]) == true)
```

you have to write either

```
if (isupper(plaintext[i]) )
```

or for example

```
if (isupper(plaintext[i]) != false)
```

because the constant `false` is equivalent to the value `0`.